# how to write test class for below code

Tags: unit-test

[image]**Apex Class**

```
public void run()
    {

        String currentuserid=UserInfo.getUserId();
        List<Id> agentIds = new List<Id>();
        for(User agent : [SELECT Id,ManagerId FROM user WHERE ManagerId=:currentuserid]){
            agentIds.add(agent.Id);
        }

        accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        contactIds = new Set<Id>();

        accList = [SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE  (ownerid=:currentuserid or ownerid IN: agentIds) ];
        if(accList.size()>0)
        {
            for (Account ac:accList)
            {

                system.debug('entered to for loop');
                accountIds.add(ac.Id);
                accountMap.put(ac.Id, ac);

            }
        }

        if(runRange=='Past 1 Week')
        {
            system.debug('past 1 week'+runRange);
            timeFrame = 7;
        }
        else if(runRange=='Past 1 Month')
        {
            timeFrame = 31;
        }
        else if(runRange=='Past 3 Month')
        {
            timeFrame = 90;             
        }

        Date last_N_Days = System.today() - timeFrame;
        taskList = [SELECT Id,Whoid,WhatId,subject,AccountId FROM Task WHERE AccountId IN:accountIds AND CreatedDate >: last_N_Days];
        eventList =[SELECT Id,Whoid,Whatid,Subject,AccountId FROM Event WHERE AccountId IN:accountIds AND CreatedDate >: last_N_Days];

        list<account> accupdate = new list<account>();
        Map<id,integer>actaskmap=New Map<id,integer>();
        Map<id,integer>accallmap=New Map<id,integer>();
        Map<id,integer>acemailmap=New Map<id,integer>();
        Map<id,integer>aceventmap=New Map<id,integer>();
        Map<id,integer>acothermap=New Map<id,integer>();
        Map<id,Accountwrapper> accountIdToWrapperMap = new Map<id,Accountwrapper>();
        Integer callCount=0;
        Integer emailCount=0;
        Integer othersCount = 0;
        Integer eventsCount = 0;

        for(task tsk:taskList){
            system.debug('entered to task loop');
            String taskSubject = tsk.Subject;
            AccountWrapper accWrapper;
            if(accountIdToWrapperMap.containsKey(tsk.AccountId)){
                accWrapper = accountIdToWrapperMap.get(tsk.AccountId);
            }
            else{
                accWrapper = new AccountWrapper(accountMap.get(tsk.AccountId),0,0,0,0,0);
            }
            if(taskSubject.containsIgnoreCase('call'))
            {
                callCount++;
                accWrapper.callcount++;
                system.debug('task sub call');
            }
            else if(taskSubject.containsIgnoreCase('Email'))
            {
                emailCount++;
                accWrapper.emailcount++;
                system.debug('task sub email');
            }
            else
            {
                othersCount++;
                accWrapper.otherscount++;
                system.debug('othersCount>>'+othersCount);
                system.debug('task sub other');
            }
            accWrapper.taskcount++;
            accountIdToWrapperMap.put(tsk.AccountId,accWrapper);
        }

        for (Event evn:eventlist){
            AccountWrapper accWrapper;
            if(accountIdToWrapperMap.containsKey(evn.AccountId)){
                accWrapper = accountIdToWrapperMap.get(evn.AccountId);
            }
            else{
                accWrapper = new AccountWrapper(accountMap.get(evn.AccountId),0,0,0,0,0);
            }
            String eventSubject = evn.Subject;
            if(eventSubject.containsIgnoreCase('Meeting')){
                eventsCount++;
                accWrapper.eventcount++;
            }
            else if(eventSubject.containsIgnoreCase('call'))
            {  
                callCount++;
                accWrapper.callcount++;
            }
            else if(eventSubject.containsIgnoreCase('Email'))
            {   
                emailCount++;
                accWrapper.emailcount++;
            }
            else{
                othersCount++;
                accWrapper.otherscount++;
            }
            accWrapper.eventcount++;
            accountIdToWrapperMap.put(evn.AccountId,accWrapper);
        }

        accWrapperList = accountIdToWrapperMap.values();


    }//run
```

**Test Class**

```
testmethod static void testrun(){


        Account acc1 = new Account();
        acc1.Name ='test';
        acc1.AccountNumber='123';
        insert acc1;
        Account acc2 = new Account();
        acc2.Name ='test1';
        acc2.AccountNumber ='231';
        insert acc2;

        list<Account>acc3 = new list<Account>();
        acc3 =[SELECT id, name FROM Account];

        Integer timeFrame = 7;

        Task tsk = new Task();
        tsk.CallDisposition ='call';
        tsk.Subject ='call';
        insert tsk;
        list<Task>tsk1 = new List<Task>();
        tsk1 =[Select Id,Subject FROM Task];
        String taskSubject = 'Call';

        AccountActivityhistory.Accountwrapper accwraper  = new AccountActivityhistory.Accountwrapper(acc1,0,0,0,0,0);


        AccountActivityhistory ref = new AccountActivityhistory();

        ref.run();
    }
```

Comment: Please do not [post under multiple accounts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238574/display-count-of-events-and-task-in-vf-page-related-to-account-and-contact-able/238633#238633). Contact Stack Exchange to have your accounts merged.

Comment: Hey man can you go through this trailhead first and try writing code on your own. If you are stuck anywhere SFSE will help you out. It's not a free code writing community. 
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro

Comment: in apex class it is not entering the for loop of task

Comment: Thanks for sharing your class, and test class. Can you please share what error you are getting when you a debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test `Task` records are not related to your `Account`.

```
Task tsk = new Task();
tsk.CallDisposition ='call';
tsk.Subject ='call';
insert tsk;
list<Task>tsk1 = new List<Task>();
tsk1 =[Select Id,Subject FROM Task];
String taskSubject = 'Call';
```

You do not set the `WhoId` or `WhatId`, so Salesforce cannot calculate the `AccountId` that your queries require:

```
    taskList = [SELECT Id,Whoid,WhatId,subject,AccountId FROM Task WHERE AccountId IN:accountIds AND CreatedDate >: last_N_Days];
    eventList =[SELECT Id,Whoid,Whatid,Subject,AccountId FROM Event WHERE AccountId IN:accountIds AND CreatedDate >: last_N_Days];
```

Set `WhatId` to the `Id` of your created `Account`.

Fundamentally, you must design your test data so that it satisfies the expectations of the code under test. `for` loops don't execute if they have no data to iterate over.

Comment: hi david reed how to set the whatid as we are inserting the account in test class

Comment: You assign the Task field `WhatId` to the `Id` of the `Account` you already created, as noted above.

Comment: hi david reed ihave modified my query                                                                            tsk1 =[SELECT Id,Whoid,WhatId,subject,AccountId FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN:acc3]; but it is not entering for loop i have attached the picture also above

Comment: I understand the problem. You did not need to change your query. You need to write one assignment statement in your test class, as I've already said.

Comment: hi david reed      are you saying something like this                                                                                               
      Task tsk = new Task();
        tsk.CallDisposition ='call';
        tsk.Subject ='call';
        tsk.WhatId ='001O000001Fgnmb';
        insert tsk;

Comment: The Id of *the Account you created in the test class*. You cannot use a hard-coded Id from outside test context.

Comment: Thank you david reed for your patience  and your suggesition is helpful to me

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I really encourage completing the Unit Testing module on Trailhead. It will help you understand some of the parameters you need to build this kind of code.

Comment: definitely i will go through the trailhead

Comment: hi david reed the same test class is failing today with same error not entering for loop after passing whatid